# Strange local variable change after calling fscanf

Tags: c++

I have this piece of code which read some parameters from files:

```
int readInput()
{
    cfFile = fopen(CONFIGFILE,"r");
    inFile = fopen(INPUTFILE,"r");
    fscanf(cfFile,"%d",&player);
    fscanf(inFile,"%d%d%d%d",&remaining[0],&remaining[1],&lastRow,&lastCol);
    char line[boardWidth+1];
    for (int i=0;i<boardHeight;++i)
    {
        //int l = i;
        fscanf(inFile,"%s",line);
        for (int j=0;j<boardWidth;++j)
        {
            int val = 0;
            if (line[j] == 'r') val = 0;
            if (line[j] == 'b') val = 1;
            if (line[j] == '_') val = 2;
            if (line[j] == 'x') val = 3;
            M[i][j]=val;
        }
    }
    fclose(cfFile);
    fclose(inFile);
}
```

When I ran, it gave me memory error. Turned out that the value of `i` was changed after the `fscanf(inFile,"%s",line)` to `2403` or something. It is very strange. If I add the line `int l = i` above, it runs without error, but changing this to `int l` doesn't work. I've also tried to change the length of line to `boardWidth + 2` and the code runs infinitely.

Anyone can explain what's happening in this situation? Because although the code with the added line ran, I'm still afraid of unseen bugs.

Comment: Make a complete test case with all variable declarations and a main

Comment: Make sure there is no memory leak in the other part of the code.

Comment: Add a sample of the file triggering the problem.

Comment: Possibly the line in a file is longer than your `line` buffer, so data read by `fscanf()` overflowed it and some other part of the stack got overwritten. And variable `i` is stored somewhere in that area, so got overwritten, too.

Comment: thanks everybody, i've checked the other codes, turned out the program generated the input file output 1 more char than the line in the code above so it caused the bug. it's was the other guys work so i didn't check it thoroughly (he used <=). my bad. :))

Comment: use `%100s` or whatever your size is instead of `%s`; or use `fgets`.

Comment: `fscanf` with `%s` is just as dangerous as `gets`. Never use it.

Comment: Try printing what it is reading. Additionally, make sure that there is no memory leak in other parts of your code.

Answer (score 0):

what is the definition of line? It is (very) probable you are read more characters than the variables size.